# Revert MS Access file without backup

Tags: ms-access

I was using an Access file a colleague of mine created. They run it without issue on their computer all the time, but when I tried running it on mine, without modifying it, I had a value prompt window come up that isn't supposed to.

I think there's some sort of auto save feature on this file because even after closing it without saving, this message shows up and I'm no longer able to run the macro within the Access file. This file is stored on a shared network drive and file history isn't enabled on this drive nor on my machine. I'm not too familiar with Access and my colleague is on leave for some time. No one else seems to know Access very well either. Is there a way than I can restore the file or the queries/macro inside it to how they were before I opened it?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Does this mean there's nothing I can do about this situation?

Comment: I added a more extensive answer, but it doesn't really provide much more help.  To get further assistance, you should include more details about the macros and the prompts, including exact wording of prompts and/or errors, etc.  Be more precise about the macro; rather than saying "no longer able to run", describe exactly what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what is or is not happening.  Is the macro no longer listed in the Navigation Pane?  Does an error occur?

Comment: The macro takes numerous Excel spreadsheets and creates tables from them to join identical fields so to avoid doing this manually. When I ran it on my computer, I get an value prompt message which isn't supposed to occur. Upon inspection of the query, I saw it attempted to join on a field [=ItemNo] when it should have simply been [ItemNo]. I have no idea as to how that change was made as I simply ran the query. I made the correction but still have similar issues with other prompts that I cannot rectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is No.  If something really was changed, there is no automatic history that can be used to recover changed settings or macros.

I realize it doesn't help to say anything now, but I am very surprised if there are no backups for the shared network drive.  Is there no IT personnel that can assist?  Regardless of whether or not you can get the file working, I would immediately make your own manual backup of the Access database file(s).  (As long as you have a backup... or even better multiple backups, Access files can simply be restored from the original using file copy and paste.)

"Autosave" is an understatement with Access, because unlike a word processing document or spreadsheet which can be held completely in memory, a database file is constantly updated.  There is no in-memory context for the database file as a whole.  Access will almost immediately update the file once it is opened, simply because it manages things like file locks, etc. The database may have an Autoexecute macro or other code that runs automatically, but this may be accompanied by security prompts, especially if you haven't opened it on that computer before. For standard forms, changes to data on a form are saved to disk immediately and no "Save" button is required. Certain aspects of the database file should not changed unless explicitly told to do so, and these are usually design aspects not change accidentally.

Comment: Thanks again for a thorough response. I replied to your other comment, but I feel this adequately addresses the issue. I will check with IT to see if they have a backup.

Comment: If IT does have a backup, make sure that you have made your manual backup already, or make the special request that they no simply overwrite the existing file.  I have no idea of your data, but at least in my case, a past backup might preserve the data schema (include macros, etc.), but the data itself will certainly have changed.  You may need to transfer current data into the restored copy of the database with working schema, but I would wait until your colleague with more understanding of Access returns before you tackle that task.

Comment: I'm hoping the schema is preserved or at least the macro. I'm not so worried about the data itself. Thank you so much for your help!